# I want to change the format of the points in exam class to ... / 5

Tags: exam

I want to change the format of the question points. So instead of [5], I want to make it: ... /5.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12 pt,a4paper,addpoints]{exam}
\pointsinleftmargin 
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question[5] First question
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

I've tried with this:

```
\pointformat{... / \pointsofquestion}
```

But that doesn't work

Comment: @clemens Perfect!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\pointformat{\ldots/\thepoints}` (and `\pointname{}` if you want to supress the name):

```
\documentclass[12 pt,a4paper,addpoints]{exam}
\pointsinleftmargin

\pointformat{\ldots/\thepoints}
\pointname{}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question[5] First question
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]